# Is there any way to tell if a question is community wiki in the July 2009 SO dump?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-wiki, data-dump

Is there any way to tell if a question is community wiki in the July 2009 Stack Overflow data dump?

There seems to be no field for "is wiki."

Comment: CC-WIKI will be in the next dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed and exists in the latest dumps